# Один js файл для разных страниц

Tags: javascript

Использую один js файл для разных страниц сайта.
Возникает проблема. Не все функции нужны на каждой странице. Поэтому после подключения скрипта делаю вставку и пишу, какие функции мне понадобятся.

Но когда смотрю чужие скрипты, таких вставок я никогда не вижу. Как правильно подключать функции на страницу?

Примечание:
мой код обычно выглядит вот так

```
<script src="code.js"></script>
<script>
  toDoSome();
  toDoSome1();
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: "делаю вставку" - вставку чего?

Comment: обновил вопрос, чтобы пояснить

Comment: Непонятно, зачем это?

Comment: Просто нужно качественне разделять скрипты для разных страниц или есть другой метод?

Comment: andreymal, как правило делаю один скрипт для нескольких страниц

Comment: Согласен, вопрос дурацкий, но хочется понять в чем ошибка, чтобы не совершать

Comment: Всё ещё непонятно зачем и в чём проблемы. Надо вам вызвать часть функций - вызывайте, никто не запрещает)

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин и что, то что Вы делаете, позволяет Вам "разделять скрипты для разных страниц"?

Comment: Я просто всегда так и делал, но на других сайтах я не такого подхода не замечал. Задумался, может что-то не так делаю

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин Да, Вы делаете не так. Никакого смысла в этих вызовах нет. Все функции из файла "code.js" все равно уже есть/доступны для кода данной страницы.

Comment: Выделите необходимые функции в отдельный файл и подключайте только его

Comment: Дмытрык, спасибо, видимо это и есть самый правильный вариант

Comment: Ну.. Можно сделать небольшой скрипт, который при вызове функции будет проверять её наличие.. Если функции нет, то просто взять её код из файла(перед этим все функции распихать по файлам .txt) и инициализировать через Function.. Это довольно интересное решение, как по-мне)